# Rerunning app always throws java.net.BindException and have to restart server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have created Java Web application that has a application listener and that listener creates thread on context initialized that creates ServerSocket that accepts new connections in a loop.

The problem is that every time I re deploy app it gives me java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed). I have closed the ServerSocket and don't know what else to do. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int port = Integer.parseInt(conf.getConf("port"));

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
        while (work) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("User connected!");
                WorkThread workThread = new WorkThread(conf, socket, bpk);
                workThread.start();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your server application is still running (and it is) then you haven't closed the server socket (it's still listening).

Comment: I have checked that, stopped the application, undeployed and checked on my pc the socket is still taken by java

Comment: You have closed the `ServerSocket` where? In a context-destroyed listener?

Comment: Well I used try-with-resource inside run method shown above and ServerSocket implements Closeable so that should be enough, right?

Comment: Only if this thread ever exits. What are you doing to cause that? And get it out of the blocking `accept()`?

Comment: This thread exists because the code is working correctly, the only problem is when making changes and redeploy it on server. If you are wondering when do I create that thread I do it when the context is initalized using application listener. I get out of accept by using another Java program that I made that sends message to the port that this server is listening.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question in any way. What are you doing to *stop* this thread? And make it exit its try-with-resources block? And/or close the socket? Answer: evidently, nothing. *Ergo* it is still running across the redeploy: *ergo* you can't bind the socket a second time.

Comment: Thank you! I realised what I have to do and it solved my problem